# "when I start an Intent, Android pops up a "Complete Action Using" dialog."

Tags: android, android-dialog

Can anyone provide an example with source code for:

"when I start an Intent, Android pops up a "Complete Action Using" dialog."

Comment: It might help if you gave us a bit more information.

Answer (score 2):

Android will show that dialog when there are two or more applications that have declared in their manifests that they handle the same intent. What you need in order to demonstrate this behavior is two sample applications that respond to the same intent - you could just find a simple Hello World example, clone it and modify the manifest to give one of them different name, and a third app that calls `startActivity()` with that same intent.

Comment: can you help me with the code?

Comment: @user1233171 - bytebender answer has the relevant code you need.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are wanting your app listed as one of the choices...** You'll need to do 2 things... Here is the code for the Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    }
}
```

Then you will need to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourPageActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The complete list of actions and their data can be found here if you don't want to use .SEND

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

You'll want to use the constant value in the AndroidManifest.xml so for example ACTION_SEARCH would be "android.intent.action.SEARCH"

**If you are wanting to bring up the list of choices from your app...**

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String value = txtLongUrl.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value);
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

for a working example see [DBitly](http://bit.ly/mz6DIB)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see this popup, try to carry out an action that has multiple existing applications in place to handle it.

For example, send yourself a text message with an e-mail address in it.  The e-mail address will turn into a link that you can touch, and the default options will make the `Complete action using` popup appear, offering `Gmail` and `Mail`.